# Using the Value of a String as an Array Name in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, class

I am trying to set the value of HTML `name` and `id` attributes using a class method that I wrote. The idea is that the value of the `name` attribute end up being like this: `name="key[field_name]"`.

I have this working if I hard code `key` so that it is `name="key[' . $field_name . ']"` however is defeats the purpose of having the class do all the heavy lifting since this is for a WordPress custom post type.

So instead I created a class parameter, `post_type_key` that will contain the value. But when I go to combine them, it does not work and all I get a `name="k"`.

I looked and the only solution I could find quickly was to use `eval()` which I definitely want to avoid doing.

Here is the relevant code:

```
$post_key = $this->post_type_key;

if ( $field_type == 'text' ) {
   $meta_field .= '<input type="' . $field_type . '" name="'.
   $post_key[$field_id_name ] . '" id="' . $field_id_name . 
   '" value="' . $meta[$field_id_name][0] . '" />';
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$this->post_type_key` (using `var_dump` ideally)? What is the value of `$field_id_name` (same)?

Comment: @Jeto The come back as `string(3) "key"` and `string(10) "first_name"` respectively.

Comment: Hence `$post_key` (which you assign from `$this->post_type_key`) isn't an array, but a string. So `$post_key[$field_id_name]` doesn't make much sense (there it returns the first character of the string "key" because `$field_id_name` is evaluated as 0).

Comment: But is there a way to create an array using the value of `$post_key` as the name?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it's very simple. Put two dollar signs before post_key: `$$post_key[$field_id_name]`.

Comment: @jh1711 That results in `name` in the HTML output. No `=` or any value

Comment: What PHP Version do you use? If it's bellow 7, you can try: `${$post_key}[$field_id_name]. If it's 7.0 or newer, I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: @jh1711I'm using v7.2.2. But I did figure it out and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to use `{}` to enclose the variable name. So:

```
name="'. $this->post_type_key[$field_id_name] . '"
```

became:

```
name="'. "{$post_key}" . '[' . $field_id_name . ']"
```

Checked the HTML and it worked and the WordPress error log was clear of the invalid string offset messages I was getting.